# How to curl in gitlab file

Tags: json, linux, curl

```
curl -k -XPATCH -H \"Content-Type: application/json\" -d '{"role":"Admin"}' https://'${admin_user}':'${admin_password}'@grafana-monitoring.'${NAMESPACE}'.test.com.example/api/orgs/1/users/2
```

I'm trying to use `curl` here and send a request to my email.

Unfortunately, the request is sent without the double quotations and semicolon, like this: `{role:Admin}`.

I've tried different solutions as mentioned above, but they didn't work. Any advice, please?

Comment: Take a look at [how to format my code block](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks)

Comment: use: `-d "{\"role\":\"Admin\"}"`

Comment: i got below issue : 
 [{"code":"UnparsableRequest","message":"Your JSON is unparseable, check your object structure."}]

Answer (score 0):

try this syntax:

```
curl -k -XPATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"role":"Admin"}' "https://${admin_user}:${admin_password}@grafana-monitoring.${NAMESPACE}.test.com.example/api/orgs/1/users/2"
```

Comment: i got below issue : 
 [{"code":"UnparsableRequest","message":"Your JSON is unparseable, check your object structure."}]

Comment: Try using double quotes for the JSON content instead:

curl -k -XPATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{\"role\":\"Admin\"}" "https://${admin_user}:${admin_password}@grafana-monitoring.${NAMESPACE}.test.com.example/api/orgs/1/users/2"

Comment: unfortunately same issue

Comment: Alternatively, you can save your JSON content in a file and use the @ symbol to include it in the curl command. Create a file, let's say filename.json, with the following content:

{"role": "Admin"}

Then, use the following curl command:

curl -k -XPATCH -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @data.json "https://${admin_user}:${admin_password}@grafana-monitoring.${NAMESPACE}.test.com.example/api/orgs/1/users/2"

Comment: Yes i tried this as well but it didn't work , I really appreciate your help

Comment: Which OS is installed in the system from which you are running curl command?

Comment: the image used is alpine

Comment: I tried to add a variable called payload with the value '{\"rule\":\"admin\"}' to my request, but upon doing so, it removed the semicolon. Therefore, the resulting output is {"rule":"admin"}